# Не работает linebreaks в django

Tags: django

Тест из поля TextField выводится одной сплошной строкой. Нашёл, что нужно использовать |linebreaks, но не помогло

```
{%for review in reviews%}
   {{review.user.name|linebreaks}}
   {{review.review_text|linebreaks}}
{%endfor%}
```

Уже не помню как решил проблему, но вот конечный код:

```
def show_product(request, pk):
  product_inf = get_object_or_404(Product, pk = pk)
  genre_inf = product_inf.book
  reviews = Review.objects.filter(product = product_inf)
  genres = Book_genre.objects.filter(book = genre_inf)

  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      Review.objects.create(
      rating = form.cleaned_data['rating'],
      review_text = form.cleaned_data['review_text'],
      user = request.user,
      product = product_inf
      )
      return redirect('/')

   context = {
    'form': form,
    'product':product_inf,
    'reviews':reviews,
    'genres': genres
   }
   return render(request, 'product.html', context)

 form = ReviewForm()
   context = {
     'form': form,
     'product':product_inf,
     'reviews':reviews,
     'genres': genres
   }
 return render(request, 'product.html', context)
```

Comment: Как вы решили проблему,можете сказать?

Comment: @Horrorzero честно уже не помню, но добавил то, что в итоге получилось. С джанго только один раз работал - вот как раз этот проект и то только помогал, поэтому вряд ли смогу что-то пояснить)